# How to debug Doctrine ODM query

Tags: doctrine-odm

Is there any way to dump the query from a Doctrine Mongodb ODM query builder.
Something like `$builder->getQuery()->toString()` is what I am looking for. Any alternative would be useful. And also a way to dump parameters.

I need to see in a particularly complex build process, where certain `$builder->addOr()` statements are getting nested.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! Missed this the first time I inspected the ODM vendor package.

```
$builder->getQuery()->debug();
```

https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/ecb96f90e8c282a42b1f103cb3011ade9f97876f/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Query/Query.php#L160